# Marshall object returned by @RequestBody

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have XML being fed into a REST controller and I use the @RequestBody annotation to transform that into a Java Object. I need to save the whole XML to a database column in addition to some specific elements from the Java Object. I am marshalling the Java object explicitly to accomplish this and that seems to be duplicate work. Is there a way to get the raw XML in addition to the parsed object while using the @RequestBody annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Let's say this is your controller method:

```
public Response yourControllerMethod(@RequestBody YourDTO dto) {
```

Simply change your @RequestBody parameter type to String and you'll get the raw body of the request:

```
public Response yourControllerMethod(@RequestBody String rawPayload) {
```

Or you can even get both:

```
public Response yourControllerMethod(@RequestBody YourDTO dto, @RequestBody String rawPayload) {
```

Comment: Get an error with the second @RequestBody annotation.    w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Stream closed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed

Comment: Is this the whole stacktrace? And which version of Spring Boot are you on?

Comment: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read document: Stream closed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Stream closed
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.readWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:227) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.readWithMessageConverters(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:147) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar

Comment: Spring Boot  version -  v1.3.1.RELEASE

Comment: I dont think you can have multiple @RequestBody annotations. The request stream is read once and converted into your Java Object OR String Object. Not both. If the stream is consumed once it is closed and cannot be read again.

Comment: @CodeItLikeAmeen All three methods work for me with Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE

Comment: @jannis Thanks for confirming.